# Why aren't links opened in new pages?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign

I use Firefox and Chrome mainly . When there is a link provided in the comment/answer/question , the link redirects to a page from the existing tab rather than opening a new tab & displaying it there.

for eg: [Left Click here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A67ZkAd1wmI) . By default , the site appears in this same tab and not in a new tab.

The same problem exists when it comes to the mobile **site**.

I'm not saying that there's anything wrong with it but why can't the links be opened in a new tab automatically rather than having to do it manually?

Comment: I agree, usually i want to open in-question links in a new tab, rather than switch. I'm pretty used to ctrl+clicking though, so I never really registered it

Comment: Use middle button (click on wheel). Problem solved. I never left-click on link if I want to open it in new tab.

Comment: nhahtdh, you're an experienced user. I'm talking in general. And btw I use my laptop's touchpad mouse. There's no wheel on it . @ToshinouKyouko since Im a noob here , I keep forgetting that the links don't open in a new page.

Comment: Anyway, it might be a problem for mobile users. It's more convenient for them to tap, than to tap-hold-select-new-tab-option to open in new tab. I think you might want to post the request on Meta.SE, since this is a network-wide issue.

Comment: Can't migrate it? :P @GaoWeiwei I know , but thanks :) . It's kinda hard on mobile too. I still feel click-for-new-page is easier in general

Comment: @EroSennin: Just ask a new question. It's faster (and doesn't harm) in this case, I think. Try to incorporate the discussion over here into your request.

Comment: @nhahtdh .. similar cases : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35677/have-all-links-open-in-a-new-tab http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/make-links-posted-by-users-open-in-a-new-window

Comment: @GaoWeiwei the guys on the SE meta are suggesting to use Ctrl+Click and MMB . Should I change my question to specify the new tab issue in phones ?

Comment: @EroSennin I think they will tell you to install the SE App, which does open all links in your default browser (behaves like opening a new window), but you could try.

Comment: @GaoWeiwei But SE App is not valid for every single internet-using phone right ? Plus this entire matter isn't about just one user.

Comment: @EroSennin The pros do not outweigh the cons, so I doubt they would cater to the ever-decreasing niche market of non-Android phones or non-iphones. It's still relatively easy to press and hold to open a new tab, or open in the same tab and pressing the back button. But as I said, you could try asking on Meta.SE.

Comment: Hmm .. point noted. But there are slow internet and other issues which make the above methods *kinda* tough. Nothing major. Will ask meta later :P @GaoWeiwei

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the default behavior when clicking on a link is to navigate the current tab to the new link. This is called the principle of least surprise.

If a user wants to open the link in a new tab, they can either

- Right click and select "Open in a new Tab/Window"
- Middle click
- CTRL+Click (yeah, that works, try it).

The only places where it makes sense to open a link in a new tab is when opening link in the same tab you'd lose some sort of progress in a process/activity (for instance, in chat).